# react set style value to unset

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

A component has `right` and `bottom` css properties that are set using a classname. And I wanted to overide those values using the `style` prop. But so far I could set numerical values like `10px` or `0px` and others, but was unable to set it to `unset`.

So what can I do to set them to `unset`? So far I tried this

```
<CTAButton position="relative" style={{right:"", bottom:""}}/>
```

And

```
<CTAButton position="relative" style={{right:null, bottom:null}}/>
```

Or

```
<CTAButton position="relative" style={{right:undefined, bottom:undefined}}/>
```

Which all failed. How can I do this?

Comment: Where are the classes? This is a custom component so it's hard to tell if the style props are even being passed down correctly. Also, have you tried using "initial"?

Comment: Or you could use the property "unset", which I can't see if you've tried this in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<CTAButton position="relative" style={{right:"unset", bottom:"unset"}}/>
```

unset can be applied to any CSS property, including the CSS shorthand all.
Just my suggestion but I am sure that it is allright.
Thanks.